# Servlet Dispatcher Issue when upgrading to spring 4.1 with xml config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets, spring-4

I'm scratching my head.

I've got an application using spring 3.2 xml based config that I'm upgrading to spring 4.X, ideally 4.3.7 (this is to simplify things, as I'm actually also upgrading hibernate, etc).  I managed to replicate the issue when/if I migrate to say 4.0.6 (less than 4.1) everything works fine.

I tried instead multiple 4.1.X and 4.3.X and practically I get no mapping resolution from the servlet.

https://localhost:8443/oldApp/home

results in

2017-04-03 12:06:40,383 WARN  {OLDAPP}[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/oldApp/home] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc' 
2017-04-03 12:06:40,383 WARN  {OLDAPP}[org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound] - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/oldApp/404] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring-mvc'

Basically, it attempts to go to the mapping of /home but fails, gets redirected to 404 as per configuration and fails also the mapping of /404..

**applicationContext-mvc.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">          

        <mvc:annotation-driven/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.verification.migration.controller.*" />
    <!-- Static resources -->
    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving 
        up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" order="0" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/favicon.ico" location="/favicon.ico" order="0" />  
    <mvc:resources mapping="/robots.txt" location="/robots.txt" order="0" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/css/**" location="/css/" order="0" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/js/libs/**" location="/js/libs/" order="0" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/**" location="/img/" order="0" />
    <mvc:resources mapping="/img/flags/**" location="/img/flags/" order="0" />



    <!-- Welcome page -->
    <mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="redirect:/home"/>

    <!--  wrapper of org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver -->
    <bean id="multipartResolver" class="com.verification.migration.util.DropOversizeFilesMultipartResolver">
        <!-- the maximum file size in bytes -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="500000000000000000"/>
        <property name="maxInMemorySize">
        <value> 50000000 </value>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Message internalization by using a db -->
    <bean id="messageSource" class="com.verification.migration.util.DatabaseMessageSource">
        <property name="messageRepository" ref="messageRepository" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver">
        <!-- <property name="defaultLocale" value="en_UK"/> -->
    </bean>

    <mvc:interceptors>
        <bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <property name="paramName" value="ln" />
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptors>

    <!-- THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for email templates -->
    <bean id="emailTemplateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="templates/" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="checkExistence" value="true" />
        <property name="order" value="1" />
    </bean>

    <!-- THYMELEAF: Template Resolver for webapp pages templates -->
    <bean id="webTemplateResolver"
        class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresolver.SpringResourceTemplateResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".html" />
        <property name="templateMode" value="HTML" />
        <property name="cacheable" value="false" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="checkExistence" value="true" />
        <property name="order" value="2" />
    </bean> 

    <bean id="templateEngine" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine">
        <property name="templateResolvers">
            <set>
                <ref bean="emailTemplateResolver" />
                <ref bean="webTemplateResolver" />
            </set>
        </property> 

          <!-- These lines configure the dialects to use with Thymeleaf -->
          <property name="dialects">
            <set>
              <bean class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.dialect.SpringStandardDialect"/>

            </set>
          <!-- Table4j additional dialect  -->
          </property>       
          <property name="additionalDialects">
            <set>
                <bean class="org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect"/>
            </set>
          </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafViewResolver">
        <property name="templateEngine" ref="templateEngine" />
        <property name="contentType" value="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
        <property name="characterEncoding" value="UTF-8" /> 
    </bean>

</beans>
```

while the **web.xml** is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
metadata-complete="true" version="3.0">

<display-name>OLDAPP</display-name>

<description></description>

<!-- Character encoding filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Spring-security filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Multipart Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MultipartFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>MultipartFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>/*</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- CAS filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>CAS Single Sign Out Filter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!--  Session timemout Filter -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.verification.migration.filter.SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>SessionTimeoutCookieFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Parameters for make autowire possible inside filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
       classpath:applicationContext.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath:applicationContext*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- If the environment variable -Dspring.profiles.active is not set the default profile is local -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>spring.profiles.default</param-name>
    <param-value>local</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Simple context initializer that log current envirnoment profile used 
    by the webapplication  -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextInitializerClasses</param-name>
    <param-value>com.verification.migration.util.ContextProfileInitializer</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <description>Servet Listener used to avoid ClassLoader Memory Leak</description>
    <listener-class>com.verification.migration.util.DciContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jasig.cas.client.session.SingleSignOutHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:applicationContext-mvc.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>spring-mvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/403</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>405</error-code>
    <location>/405</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.bind.MissingServletRequestParameterException</exception-type>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.bind.ServletRequestBindingException</exception-type>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException</exception-type>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <error-code>400</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Restricted methods</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>PUT</http-method>
        <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
        <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
        <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint/>
</security-constraint>

<session-config>
    <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    <cookie-config>
        <http-only>true</http-only>
    </cookie-config>
    <tracking-mode>COOKIE</tracking-mode>
</session-config>
```

HomeController.java

```
package com.verification.migration.controller;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import jxl.write.WriteException;
import nl.captcha.Captcha;
import nl.captcha.servlet.CaptchaServletUtil;

import org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.beans.propertyeditors.StringTrimmerEditor;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.validation.Errors;
import org.springframework.validation.FieldError;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.WebDataBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.InitBinder;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.SessionAttributes;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus;
    import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
    import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;
    import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.RedirectAttributes;

    import com.google.common.base.Optional;
    import com.google.common.collect.FluentIterable;
    import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
    import com.googlecode.flyway.core.Flyway;

    @SessionAttributes({ "userLogged", "mpFields"})
    @Controller
    public class HomeController {

        private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory
                .getLogger(HomeController.class);

        @Value("${receipt.folder}")
        private String RECEIPT_FOLDER;

    @RequestMapping(value = { "/home", "/homeprivate" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String entryPoint(Model model, Locale locale,
                HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                SessionStatus sessionStatus) {
            model.addAttribute("isHomepage", "true");
            return "homepage";
        }
    }
```

As this seems to work with both 3.2.X (old version and dependency) and 4.0.6 (the VERY same file I've posted here, with just different maven dependency version pointing to spring-core and spring MVC 4.0.X) I'm inclined to think that something must have changed with 4.1 as far as XML config are concerned, as I have other application running just fine with 4.3.7 using java config..
The old version was also using Thymeleaf2, and I upgraded to Thymeleaf3, but it's not the culprit, as using spring 4.0.6 I managed to get the application running flawlessly both with Thymeleaf2 and Thymeleaf3. Same apply to upgrade in  hibernate version.

Thus I pinpointed it to spring, as by just upgrading from spring spring 3.2.2 --> spring 4.0.6 (and modifying ONLY if needed, as there is some dependency switch from spring3 to spring4) it works--> spring 4.1.9 without touching anything apart from spring (core, mvc,etc) the dispatching of calls fails...

Anyone can point out what I'm completely missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: as a workaround I changed applicationContext-mvc.xml to reference a java config file that would handle the mvc, and it works..
this just confirms that there is something that is done properly in my xml files..
but as there are no "change" documented in the 4.0.X to 4.1.X  regarding spring mvc xml config files, rather than blaming me, I'll blame it on the lack of documentation..
If no one provides an alternative, i'll put this as an answer and mark the question as solved, but I'd *really* prefer reaching a proper resolution and not just "making it work" one way or the other....

Answer (score 0):

As I received no answer on this topic, I'll just produce an answer myself, which is sort of an hack in itself, but at least allowed me to go through..

I changed applicationContext-mvc.xml to reference a java config file that in turn handles the configuration..
while this works, this just confirms that there is something that isn't done properly in my xml files, but as there are no "change" documented in the 4.0.X to 4.1.X regarding spring mvc xml config files, I'll blame it on the lack of documentation..

So be forewarned that when switching to 4.1.x from 3.X or 4.0.X, you might have some trouble and I'd suggest that if you can't figure what's exactly wrong (just like I failed to do), using an xml config declaring an component scan of the java config (solely for the mvc) to kickstart the mvc component of your application will make do..

Not the most beautiful things, but that's the only solution I came up with...